# Rails 5 / JavaScript: dynamically update only record attributes that have updated on page

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-5, decorator

I'm following the presenter/decorator pattern where I have a separate wrapper class for a record that adds additional functionality like formatting attributes, etc...

My presenters also wrap the attributes in a `span` tag that has a unique DOM ID reference:

`<span data-behavior="user_1_full_name">John Smith</span>`

This allows me to update the attribute dynamically with JavaScript without updating the whole page.  Note that I'm using `data-behavior` because `ID and CLASS` should be left for CSS styling IMO and it avoids conflicts.

```
User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
end

UserPresenter < SimpleDelegator
  def initialize(record, view_context = nil)
    @record = record
    @view_context = view_context
  end

  # Iterate over this to dynamically update
  def attributes_to_update
    [:full_name, :first_name, :last_name].freeze
  end

  # ie, "John Smith"
  def full_name
    text = [@record.first_name, @record.last_name].join(" ")
    attribute_wrapper(:full_name, text)    
  end

  private

  # Wraps attributes in unique data-behavior wrapper:
  # ie: <span data-behavior="user_1_full_name">John Smith</span>
  def attribute_wrapper(attribute, value)
    @view_context.content_tag :span, value, data: { behavior: "#{dom_id(@record)}_#{attribute}".strip }
  end
end
```

This works, and I'm able to update the attributes dynamically with JavaScript using those `data-behavior` attributes.

However, I have a model that has 30+ of these attributes.  The presenter stores an array of the attributes to update, so I can update them in a `js.erb` view file with a few lines of code:

```
# app/views/users/update.js.erb with jQuery
<%= @user_presenter.attributes_to_update.each do |attribute| %>
  $("[data-behavior='user_<%= @user.id %>_<%= attribute %>]").replaceWith("<%=j @user.public_send(attribute) %>");
<% end %>
```

The problem is, when I just update a single field, it will update all 30+ of them.  Outside of using a full-blown front-end framework like React, is there a clean way to only update attributes that have changed?

I'm fine with using vanilla JS or any StimulusJS solutions or even small libraries, but am not trying to write everything on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

use a small virtual DOM library such as HyperHTML. They are several other libraries like this, you can Google them. I have used HyperHtml in the past and it works great

https://github.com/WebReflection/hyperHTML

**Solution 2**
If you are using Stimulus you could keep track of each of the field value and store them in a data attribute using the Stimulus API `data.set("field-name"). It is a string so if you want to store an object you need to stringify it first. Then only update the fields if the value has changed. 
more information in the Stilulus documentation

https://stimulusjs.org/handbook/managing-state